# Why does YouTube change my lock screen wallpaper and how do I prevent that?

Tags: lock-screens, youtube

When I'm watching YouTube videos on my phone, and then lock my phone, my wallpaper is replaced by the thumbnail of the video I was watching.

Removing YouTube from the recent applications screen does not change that. I don't get why that would be useful, and it certainly looks ugly.

Where can I disable that?

Comment: Never happened with me. Are you using the official YouTube app? Do you have premium subscription red/pro? What is your country? Is picture in picture mode enabled?

Comment: It's the official YouTube app on LineageOS. I don't have YouTube Red and AFAIK it's required for picture in picture mode. I live in Poland. @singhnsk

Comment: I have a one plus 5 and this is driving me up the wall. Even if I quit YouTube, and set my lock screen from settings, it persists. It might be when I watch videos through Chrome rather than YouTube itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found that swiping away the YouTube mini player in the notifications area clears its picture on the lock screen.

The notification survives closing YouTube and swiping the app away from the apps list, but it can be swiped away itself.

But I wish it didn't happen at all.